# Show/Hide content by checking 2 differen URLS first

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm running a code that displays content based on the url. If the user is in page X, the page displays the content number 1 and hides number 2, if he's in page Y, it displays the content number 2 and hides number 1. It works, but I would like to add a second URL to be checked.

My code is as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  var url = document.location.href;
    if(url == "http://w.com/") {
$(".banner1").show();
$(".adsenselistingtop").show();
$("#leheaderbanner").hide();
$("#showhide-in-home").hide();

  } else {
      $(".banner1").hide();
      $(".adsenselistingtop").hide();
      $("#leheaderbanner").show();
      $("#showhide-in-home").show();
  }



});
```

I tried using something like this, but it didn't work:

```
 if(url == "http://w.com/" && url == "http://w.com/index.php") {
```

Comment: May be something like:  if(url == "http://w.com/" || url == "http://w.com/index.php") {

Comment: please post it as an answer, it worked, but the `;` should be removed, as it's an unexpected token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use OR instead of AND as the URL can be either of them.

```
if(url == "http://w.com/" || url == "http://w.com/index.php")
```

Comment: Count down to accept the best answer. 15 seconds. ;)

Comment: Annnnd there you go. Thx

Comment: Haha! Thank You :)